# Calculating mean of data frame inside a series object

Tags: pandas, ipython

I have a data frame with following structure:

```
df.columns

Index(['first_post_date', 'followers_count', 'friends_count', 'last_post_date','min_retweet', 'retweet_count', 'screen_name', 'tweet_count',  'tweet_with_max_retweet', 'tweets', 'uid'],
      dtype='object')
```

Inside the *tweets* series, each cell is another data frame containing all the tweets of an user.

```
df.tweets[0].columns

Index(['created_at', 'id', 'retweet_count', 'text'], dtype='object')
```

I want to perform calculation on the *tweets* of each users, for example, finding average number of retweets of each user, the tweet with maximum retweets etc.

How can I do these?

**Edit**
[link to sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/67we61wydrrdhyk/subsampled.pickle?dl=0)

Comment: Can you upload a few lines of data so we can present a working solution?

Comment: @Emre, link added

Comment: @Emre, I loaded the data in data frame using pandas.read_pickle(filename)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) (the Right Way$^\mathrm{TM}$), the `apply` method can do what you want; e.g.

```
df.assign(
    max_retweet=df.tweets.apply(lambda x: x.retweet_count.argmax('retweet_count')),
    avg_retweet=df.tweets.apply(lambda x: x.retweet_count.mean())
)


       avg_retweet  max_retweet  
26662     0.045476          187  
32316     0.821538          427  
25879     0.633681          583  
43411     0.112465          421  
28840     0.472222            8
```

Also, don't share data with pickle; it's [dangerous](https://www.kevinlondon.com/2015/08/15/dangerous-python-functions-pt2.html).

Comment: I have a similar data structure and `apply` method seems not work for my situation. Can you help me to solve my problem?
https://hackmd.io/s/ryrCfAjZG

Comment: Please post a new question at StackOverflow.